# rotate an image without using OpenCV in python 3

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to rotate an image in python with nearest neighbor and bilinear interpolations without using OpenCv library and here's my approach:

```
import matplotlib.image as img
import numpy as npy
import math

m = img.imread("room.png");

w, h = m.shape[:2];

newImage = npy.zeros([w,h, 4]);

for i in range(w - 1):
    for j in range(h - 1):
        newImage[i , j] = m[int(math.cos(30)*(i-w/2)+math.sin(30)*(j-h/2) + w/2),int(math.cos(30)*(j-h/2)-math.sin(30)*(i-w/2) + h/2)]

img.imsave('rotated.png', newImage);
```

but I couldn't find why doesn't it work fine, here's the error I've gotten:

IndexError: index 852 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 852

Comment: When rotating the coordinates, some pixels end up outside the original image. You need to test your computed coordinates and fill in 0 if they’re outside the input image.

Comment: Keep in mind that math.sin and math.cos take radian angles...I would suggest replacing your 30 by npy.pi/6 ...but this is not the source of your problem. When you rotate a square image at the same scale, the output image will be bigger or you need to crop it.

Comment: @ma3oun yeah I changed it, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1):

I should have determined what if the coordinates of a pixel ended up outside the original image:

```
for i in range(w - 1):
    for j in range(h - 1):
        pixelNewX = int(math.cos(math.pi/6)*(i-w/2)+math.sin(math.pi/6)*(j-h/2)+w/2)
        pixelNewY = int(math.cos(math.pi/6)*(j-h/2)-math.sin(math.pi/6)*(i-w/2)+h/2)
        if 0 <= pixelNewX < w and 0 <= pixelNewY < h :
            newImage[i, j] = m[pixelNewX, pixelNewY]
```